# spark: join rdd based on sequence of another rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an rdd say `sample_rdd` of type `RDD[(String, String, Int))]` with 3 columns id,item,count. sample data:

`id1|item1|1
 id1|item2|3
 id1|item3|4
 id2|item1|3
 id2|item4|2`

I want to join each id against a `lookup_rdd` this:

`item1|0
 item2|0
 item3|0
 item4|0
 item5|0`

The output should give me following for id1, outerjoin with lookuptable:

`item1|1
 item2|3
 item3|4
 item4|0
 item5|0`

Similarly for id2 i should get:

`item1|3
 item2|0
 item3|0
 item4|2
 item5|0`

Finally output for each id should have all counts with id:

`id1,1,3,4,0,0
 id2,3,0,0,2,0`

**IMPORTANT:this output should be always ordered according to the order in lookup**

This is what i have tried:

`val line = rdd_sample.map { case (id, item, count) => (id, (item,count)) }.map(row=>(row._1,row._2)).groupByKey()
get(line).map(l=>(l._1,l._2)).mapValues(item_count=>lookup_r‌​dd.leftOuterJoin(ite‌​m_count))`

`def get (line: RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, Int)])]) = { for{ (id, item_cnt) <- line i = item_cnt.map(tuple => (tuple._1,tuple._2)) } yield (id,i)`

Comment: `val line = rdd_sample.map { case (id, item, count) => (id, (item,count)) }.map(row=>(row._1,row._2)).groupByKey()
`

Comment: `get(line).map(l=>(l._1,l._2)).mapValues(item_count=>lookup_rdd.leftOuterJoin(item_count))`

function:

`def get (line: RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, Int)])]) = {
    for{
      (id, item_cnt) <- line
      i = item_cnt.map(tuple => (tuple._1,tuple._2))
      } yield (id,i)
  }`

Comment: you can edit that into the question.

Comment: @NanditaDwivedi did you try out the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. Run each step on your local console to understand whats happening in detail.

The idea is to zipwithindex and form seq based on lookup_rdd.
`(i1,0),(i2,1)..(i5,4)` and `(id1,0),(id2,1)`

```
Index of final result wanted = [delta(length of lookup_rdd seq) * index of id1..id2 ] + index of i1...i5
```

So the base seq generated will be `(0,(i1,id1)),(1,(i2,id1))...(8,(i4,id2)),(9,(i5,id2))`

and then based on the key`(i1,id1)` reduce and calculate count.

```
val res2 = sc.parallelize(arr) //sample_rdd
val res3 = sc.parallelize(cart) //lookup_rdd
val delta = res3.count

val res83 = res3.map(_._1).zipWithIndex.cartesian(res2.map(_._1).distinct.zipWithIndex).map(x => (((x._1._1,x._2._1),((delta * x._2._2) + x._1._2, 0)))

val res86 = res2.map(x => ((x._2,x._1),x._3)).reduceByKey(_+_)

val res88 = res83.leftOuterJoin(res86)

val res91 = res88.map( x => {
    x._2._2 match {
       case Some(x1) => (x._2._1._1, (x._1,x._2._1._2+x1))
       case None => (x._2._1._1, (x._1,x._2._1._2))
    }
})

val res97 = res91.sortByKey(true).map( x => {
(x._2._1._2,List(x._2._2))}).reduceByKey(_++_)

res97.collect

// SOLUTION: Array((id1,List(1,3,4,0,0)),(id2,List(3,0,0,2,0)))
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it works! But is this approach good if lookup_rdd has 6k ids and sample_rdd file can be upto 10GB

Comment: can you try it out and post the performance ? I dont have that much data.